# Git removes files from staging area after unsuccessful "push and commit"

Tags: eclipse, git

I tried to "push and commit" files using Eclipse.

But failed due to lost of VPN connection.

After error message, Git removes all files from staging area of Eclipse.

Files are not visible at command line (Git status) as well.

How can i push it to branch now ?

Comment: Have you loggedin to github website and checked if your changes are actually lost?

Comment: Probably, the files have been committed but not pushed. Check what your latest local commit is: `git log -1`
Most likely that commit contains your changes.

Comment: I don't know what *Eclipse* is doing (I don't use Eclipse), but Git literally *cannot* push anything that is not committed. It seems likely that this is "commit first, then push". You should therefore find out what Eclipse has done with the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Alderath is right. Right click on your branch from 'Git Repositories' view in eclipse, and click on 'Push Branch...'.